# Change textblock text on click of rectangle using XAML triggers

Tags: wpf, eventtrigger

```
 void rectForeHead_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        txtLableBlock.Text += rectForeHead.ToolTip;
    }

    void rectChest_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        txtLableBlock.Text += rectChest.ToolTip;
    }
```

I am changing textblock text property on click of number of rectangles.
How can I achieve the same with WPF Event triggers